# if (view == null) issues in fragment

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have updated my Sdk Oreo 8.0 When i come my current fragment to my previous fragment its crash because i am using if (view == null) 
if i removed this condition it 'll work fine but have to load again view.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragement_layout, container, false);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            bundle=getArguments();
            registrationResponse=(RegistrationResponse)bundle.getSerializable("registerresponse");
            setadapter();
            hitUserFavouriteOutfitsapi();
           swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        }
        toolBarTopChangeState =((ToolBarTopChangeState)context);
        toolBarTopChangeState.stateChangeToolBarIcon(0);
        toolBarTopChangeState.stateChangeToolBarText(getString(R.string.app_name));
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: remove `if (view == null) {` why `==null` checking ?

Comment: @Sanoop Its works on `ADAPTER` section.

Comment: please add the crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragement_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        bundle=getArguments();
        registrationResponse=(RegistrationResponse)bundle.getSerializable("registerresponse");
        setadapter();

        hitUserFavouriteOutfitsapi();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        toolBarTopChangeState =((ToolBarTopChangeState)context);
        toolBarTopChangeState.stateChangeToolBarIcon(0);
        toolBarTopChangeState.stateChangeToolBarText(getString(R.string.app_name));
        return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the lists is a good practice to check if the view is already created and if it's to use it further, but on the activities and fragments you should left the OS to decide when should inflate again the view. You can have a look over android lifecycle to understand better how it's works

Comment: I don't want re added view and not hit  the api if i come back my previous fragment so i check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

it 'll happen because i am adding animation when fragment change and return to back.. This problem facing because of Android 8.0(Oreo) rest os working fine so I removed the animation during fragment  change it 'll solved.